# Webview - memory allocation increasing with each article load

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, uiwebview, automatic-ref-counting

I have created one application for book reading using SplitViewController.

There is number of article list in MasterViewContoller and tapping on any article, contents loads into webview. There is memory leak with WebView as with every article load, memory allocation is increased by 4-5 MB.

Kindly let me know if anyone has came across this.

PS: DetailsViewController is created only once. Tested by using strong and weak reference for WebView.

Comment: try to use WKWebview as a starts if you app supports >iOS8 it is much lighter

Comment: Thanks @M_Waly. But our application has support 7.x and above so cannot use WKWebview.